# Type 'string' is not assignable to type for react-router-dom Link Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How the hell do I get rid of this TS error referring to the `ref="link"` prop?

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLAnchorElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLAnchorElement> | null | undefined'. 
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
```

**CompanyList.tsx**

```
export default class CompanyList extends Component<{ companies: Array<Company>, countries: Array<Country> }, any> {

        const link = (
          <Link className={className} id={company.id} ref="link" to={uri}>
            <span id="company-name">{company.name}</span>
          </Link>
        );
... rest of component
```

Here is another look at it from the IDE in another component:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ref` cannot be a `String`. It needs to be created using `React.createRef()`. Please see: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs

> Refs are created using `React.createRef()` and attached to React elements via the ref attribute. Refs are commonly assigned to an instance property when a component is constructed so they can be referenced throughout the component.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

Also note that if you're using React Router < v5.1, you need to use `innerRef` to access the DOM element. See it here: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/innerref-function

> As of React Router 5.1, if you are using React 16 you should not need this prop (`innerRef`) because we forward the ref to the underlying `<a>`. Use a normal ref instead.

Comment: I was sending in a string to this and it's working fine for react-router-dom so not sure why it needs to be a React.createRef() though

Comment: I actually think this isn't needed anymore for react-router.  I must have been using a very old version of react-router

Comment: @PositiveGuy refs can only be created using `React.createRef()`. There is no other way to create a ref.

Comment: Does this answer your question?